# Draw Texture2D atlas inside Texture Array

Tags: c++, opengl, texture2d, texture-atlas

How to draw via GLSL Sampler only part of Texture2D Atlas stored inside Texture Array?
For example i have Texture atlas, and i will put them together (with other atlases of same size)
inside Texture2D Array. (glTexSubImage3D)

[image]

Well, how my sampler should looks like in that case?

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)

I've found only examples, how select & apply whole texture from Array, but nothing related if inside our Array 
we store Texture Atlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily this is the area in which I have been working recently, and to use a 2d texture array in the fragment shader you can do something like the following:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2DArray tex;

flat in uint fragLayer;
in vec2 fragTexCoord;

out vec4 colour;

void main()
{
    colour = texture( tex, vec3( fragTexCoord, fragLayer ) );
}
```

So the texture layer is the 3rd element of a 3d vector used to access individual pixels in the texture array.

Also note that using the naive (and simplest) `glTexSubImage3d` straight on your raw image will only work if all your tiles are in a vertical line, not a grid.

Comment: I got texture atlases to work with array textures, but they have to be in a vertical line instead of a grid like you said. How can it be done with a grid? Can it still be done with one array texture and one pixel array pointer? I'm guessing you can just mess with the glTexSubImage3D offset parameters?

Comment: The reason you cannot use a grid is because OpenGL is not meant to be a comprehensive utility library, and so wants the pixels for each image to be fully contiguous. What can be done however, is a memory operation to turn the grid into a vertical line, then passing that into the atlas (at least that's what I do).