# How to batch multi texture when it size too big ( over 2048x2048 )?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, texture2d

I know that unity can batch UI Image with same metrail. So I want to make a Textrue atlas to do , But my texture size is too big ( over 2048x2048  ) it over the limit on mobile.
So I can't combine to one texture for batch.

Can I use multi texture at one matrail ? Or how can I do ?

[image]

Here in my game all tile will over each other , So need set one materil for keep drawcall.

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of what you are trying to do? That would really help better understand your problem.

Comment: @Ron
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562303/draw-texture2d-atlas-inside-texture-array
Here I found somebody have same problem like me . I want to build a map and one atlas size is not enough. So maybe using texture array.

Comment: @Ron I update my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do that. I would recommend going around the problem, and make sure that you really need such a large texture.

I'm a game developer in the mobile space for over 11 years, with games that reached 100m+ downloads; and I've never had to have a UI atlas larger than 2048x2048.

And in the worst case, simply use two atlases of up to 2048x2048, it's only 1 more draw call.

Comment: In my case , I want to make a map by tile , So it have a lot of difference tile and those tile over each other , if it not use same matreal It will let batch break. Now I trying use GPU Instancing with Tex2dArray Shader to batch :)

Comment: what about breaking apart your tiles to atomic components and assemble them by hand? This way you can have a lot of stuff in a single atlas

Comment: This seems to me like premature optimization - did you try building it with the sub-optimal batching and see how it runs? Today even mid-tier devices can support quite a lot of draw calls.